# REGEXP_SUBSTR equivalent in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, regexp-substr

I have an Oracle query using

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('500 Oracle Parkway, Redwood Shores, CA',',[^,]+,') 
FROM DUAL;
```

It returns the output as below:

```
, Redwood Shores,
```

I am trying to get the exact same result in SQL Server. I tried to do it as below

```
 substring(text, patindex, length)
```

But I struggled with length specification.

Can you please let me know how I can achieve this is in SQL Server?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have regular expressions. You can use the [STRING_SPLIT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt684588.aspx) table-valued function to split a string and return its parts as separate rows

Comment: i was looking for the same thing.  Didn't see any equivalence to that either!  We should suggest Micro-soft staff to develop THAT!

Answer (score 2):

You can try below query

```
WITH dual AS
(
 SELECT '500 Oracle Parkway, Redwood Shores, CA' AS st
)
SELECT SUBSTRING(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(st),
                                   CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(st)),
                                   LEN(st))),
                 CHARINDEX(',', st),
                 LEN(st)) str_value
  FROM dual
```

Below is the result which I have got

[image]

**Note: `with clause` is just for data preparation. Just make use of the `substring` part in `select statement`**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Declare @test varchar(max)='500 Oracle Parkway, Redwood Shores, CA'
select reverse(substring(reverse(substring(@test,charindex(',',@test),len(@test))),
        charindex(',',reverse(substring(@test,charindex(',',@test),len(@test)))),
        len(substring(@test,charindex(',',@test),len(@test)))))
```